# Cannot deploy backend on Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment, backend

I'm newbie on backend stuff. I need to deploy a full stack app. I'll deploy frontend to Netlify and backend to Heroku.

I've managed to deploy backend(node.js) on Heroku by terminal. However, it doesn't respond any request from fetch.

That's what I've done so far in my backend folder.

```
heroku create
git add .
git commit -am "Some commit"
git push heroku
```

So it worked and I see my backend app in Heroku. However, when I open the app,only thing I see is default 'welcome to your app' page of Heroku.

I've tried to fetch by Heroku link and all I get is 502 error. I've tested on Postman and response is just markup of default Heroku welcome page.

The error log in my terminal when I try to fetch is as below.

```
2021-03-04T11:41:52.037366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/search?q=matrix%204" host=salty-meadow-59254.herokuapp.com request_id=3b671893-c701-4319-a93a-8725063a5fd3 fwd="176.33.88.191" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Before any code has been deployed, Heroku will display a generic welcome message to its visitors. This page is served with HTTP status code 502 to indicate that the app is not yet running.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps

Heroku only deploys code that you push to master or main branch.

```
git push heroku master
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code